# Filter Firestore with multiple where not working

Tags: arrays, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have this docs

```
let wall = firebase.wallCollection;
```

then I want to filter it with multiple where:

- location (location == filterLocation)
- price (price < filterMaximumPrice)

This is my filter methods on Vue

```
filterResult(){
    let self = this;
    if(self.filterLocation!=""){
        wall.where('location','==', self.filterLocation);
        console.log("Location flag");
    }
    if(parseInt(self.filterMaximumPrice)!=0){
        dinding.where('price','<', parseInt(self.filterMaximumPrice));
        console.log("Price flag");
    }

    wall.get()
    .then(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(doc => {
        self.listFilteredWall.push(doc.data());
        }, this);
    })
}
```

The problem is that 2 where function not working and still give all wall output without filter.

How to fix this?

Comment: Mostly, this issue comes when either of the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

[CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) extends [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query).  The result of [where()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where) is a new `Query`:

> Creates a new query that returns only documents that include the
>   specified fields and where the values satisfy the constraints
>   provided.

You need to retain the result `Query` if each `where()` and use it for the `get()`.  Something like this:

```
filterResult(){
    let self = this;
    let query = wall;

    if(self.filterLocation!=""){
        query = query.where('location','==', self.filterLocation);
        console.log("Location flag");
    }
    if(parseInt(self.filterMaximumPrice)!=0){
        query = query.where('price','<', parseInt(self.filterMaximumPrice));
        console.log("Price flag");
    }

    query.get()
    .then(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(doc => {
        self.listFilteredWall.push(doc.data());
        }, this);
    })
}
```